# Matching values in one column with comma separated values in another column and returning the matched value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have one column with values like

```
himaanshu
akshay
rahul
hgeet
```

And another column with values like

```
axs,fdvf,dasad
axs,fdvf,dasad, himaanshu
axs,fdvf,dasad, akshay
asz,wesd,hgeet
```

I need to return the matching name for every row in Column 2 from whole list of Column 1

Solution Should be:

```
 1. None
 2. himaanshu
 3. akshay
 4. hgeet
```

Can anyone help me with the formula that I can use in spreadsheet to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this formula works (in a google spreadsheet)

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C5, textjoin("|", 1, A2:A5)), "none"))
```

The formula extracts any of the values in column A from the values in column C

[[image: Example[1]]

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

```
Sub test()

    Dim str1 As String
    Dim rngToSearch As Range, cell As Range
    Dim LastRowA As Long, LastrowC As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastrowC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        Set rngToSearch = .Range("C2:C" & LastrowC)

        For i = 2 To LastRowA

            str1 = .Range("A" & i).Value

            For Each cell In rngToSearch

                arr = Split(cell.Value, ",")

                For y = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

                    If Trim(arr(y)) = Trim(str1) Then
                        .Range("B" & i).Value = str1
                    End If

                Next y

            Next cell

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks foor sharing the answer.But I need to return only the matching values to search. 

Like for Row 2 - none
Row 3 - himaanshu
Row 4 - akshay
Row 5 - hgeet

Comment: @Error  Imagine `ABC,CDE,FGH` if you now lookup `AB` it will match even if `AB` does not appear in that comma separated list.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ you are write. i will remove the answer ans if i com up with a solution i will be back

Comment: @Error1004 well with VBA, but the OP specified google sheets now :/

Comment: i thought VBA was included. My bad!

Comment: @Error1004 yes, it originally was tagged both, but I asked him to precise his tags, as vba and google script are 2 completely different approaches. Sorry :/

Answer (score -1):

`=VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*", B1:B4,1,0)`

Comment: You might benefit from reading [answer]. Answers posting just code without explanations are not very useful. Consider adding an explanation to improve your answer.

Comment: Also your answer does not reflect the actual issue properly. Imagine `ABC,CDE,FGH` if you now lookup `AB` it will match even if `AB` does not appear in that comma separated list.